# Is there any way to detect phone angle on flat position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, portrait

Is there any way to get the current angle of the phone even the phone is in portrait lock and trying to capture an image by holding it in right-handed (landscape)position or left handed position(landscape)?

Whenever I capture an image through right-handed position (keeping home button to the right-hand side) am getting it correctly, but whenever I capture image through left-handed position am getting inverted image( image rotated by 180 degrees).  How to fix this issue?

I have tried this but no use, becoz orientation always will be portrait

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation=[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

     // Do Orientation operations
     if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
     {
         MYLog(@"LandRight");
         rotation = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90 * (M_PI/180))];
     }
     else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
         MYLog(@"LandLeft");
         rotation = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90 * (M_PI/180))];
     }
     else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){
         MYLog(@"porttttt");
         rotation = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0 * (M_PI/180))];
     }
     else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
     {
         MYLog(@"portupdown");
         rotation = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1 * (M_PI/180))];
     }

     else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp)
     {
         MYLog(@"faceup");
         rotation = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90 * (M_PI/180))];
     }
     [transform setValue:rotation forKey:@"inputTransform"];
     enhancedImage = [transform outputImage];
```

Capture in any more should not rotate the image at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

hope this one help for you

Comment: But if the phone is flat, it will go in to Portrait which isn't necessarily true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreMotion library with some logic deciding orientation from the raw gyroscope events.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion
Here is some sample app from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MotionGraphs/Introduction/Intro.html